# Swift: How do i insert item to array with specific order?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to insert item at specific index in Swift. But an error has occurred: `Index is out of range`

```
var a = [String]()
a.insert("a", atIndex: 3)
a.insert("b", atIndex: 1)
a.insert("c", atIndex: 0)
a.insert("d", atIndex: 2)
print(a)
```

If i have to use append or insert sequentially, it will break the order i wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by *@fiks* does explain the problem and a the correct solution if you want to use Array.

### Dictionary

Since you want to perform random insertions, using a `Dictionary` instead of `Array` does seem a more flexible choice.

```
var dict: [Int:String] = [:]
dict[3] = "a"
dict[1] = "b"
dict[0] = "c"
dict[2] = "d"

print(dict) // [2: "d", 3: "a", 1: "b", 0: "c"]
print(dict.sort { $0.0.0 < $0.1.0}.map { $0.1 } ) // ["c", "b", "d", "a"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert an item in the empty array at index 3. This causes the crash.

You may want to initialise the array with default values:

```
var a = Array<String>(count: 10, repeatedValue: "")
a.insert("a", atIndex: 3)
print(a)
```

But then you are not inserting, you are jus modifying the value, so you could achieve the same in this way:

```
var a = Array<String>(count: 10, repeatedValue: "")
a[3] = "a"
print(a)
```

Comment: This should be the answer, I guess!!

Comment: I know. I've tried it. `Array<QuotesModel>(count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)` QuotesModel is the data model. and error is: `Expression type 'Array<QuotesModel>' is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: How is your 'QuotesModel' defined?

Comment: You may also want to initialise it with optionals: `Array<QuotesModel?>(count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)`

Comment: I've tested with your way, but it still doesn't work. The question has been solved but i still don't understand insert at index mechanism. `var a = [String?](count:4,repeatedValue:nil)
a.insert("a", atIndex: 3)
a.insert("b", atIndex: 1)
a.insert("c", atIndex: 0)
a.insert("d", atIndex: 2)
print(a)` I've tested this code and it print 8 elements, it doesn't override the item at index i wanted

Comment: Based on the documentation, `insert` inserts a new item and modifies the array. If you want to just modify an item, you should access it directly: `a[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the second parameter of `insert` must be less than or equal to the array's `endIndex`.

When you want to insert an element at index 3 to an array that has zero length, you can't! Because if there is an element at index 3, there must be an element at index 0, 1, 2 as well! That's how arrays work: it's sequential.

I guess you want the elements at index 0, 1 and 2 to be some default value. Then use this extension

```
extension Array {
    mutating func insert(element: Element, atIndex index: Int, withDefaultValue value: Element) {
        if self.endIndex < index {
            let diff = index - endIndex
            for _ in 0...diff {
                self.append(value)
            }
            self[endIndex - 1] = element
        } else {
            insert(element, atIndex: index)
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty much self-explanatory.

This can also be an XY problem. You might just need a `[Int: String]` for this. But without further info, I don't know.